# Prevenir que um valor seja selecionado no dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Há alguma maneira de prevenir que um valor seja selecionado em um dropdown? Por exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('teste').onchange = function (event){
  var valor = this.value;
  if(valor == 4){
    alert('esse valor não pode!');
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="teste">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

No snippet acima, caso o valor seja 4, ele deveria cancelar a seleção, e manter o valor que estava selecionado antes. Qual a maneira certa de fazer isso? Inicialmente, estou pensando em salvar o valor e selecionar via `javascript` caso não possa selecionar determinado valor.
Aceito soluções com ou sem jquery

Comment: A forma que pensou é valida, alem de ter milhares de formas de fazer isso, mas basicamente, você está pensando da forma certa

Comment: @RafaelAugusto pensei que houvesse alguma maneira de cancelar o evento :(

Comment: Você pode explicar porque o valor não pode ser selecionado? Dependendo do caso podia dar um 'disabled' na <option>.

Comment: Eu acredito que não tenha, pelo menos nunca utilizei, mas posso estar errado. Logo logo o **Sergio** aparece por aqui é concretiza a resposta.

Comment: @RenatoDiniz é que dependendo das opções que ele tiver adicionado em um outro listbox, determinados valores não podem ser selecionados no dropdown em questão, e como ele pode mudar os valores do list a qualquer momento, achei mais simples verificar as opções do list a cada `change` do que ficar controlando os `option` que devem estar desabilitados ou não

Comment: Por que não coloca um `disabled` na opção usando o `onchage` do listbox anterior? Como o @RenatoDiniz propôs, seria mais fácil e até melhor.

Comment: Mesmo que queira fazer deste jeito que queres fazer, que acho válido tb, eu sugeriria que, quando a pessoa escolher a opção "4", em vez de mudar para o valor que estava selecionado antes, mudar para o primeiro `option`mesmo. Acho esse recurso supérfluo.

Comment: Quando a pessoa selecionar o "4", dá o alerta e tudo e volta pro primeiro `option` com `document.getElementById('teste').selectedIndex = 0;`. Simples e sem muitos códigos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deixar a opção habilitada para que o usuário a selecione, e esperar que ele faça isso para exibir uma alerta dizendo que não pode... Isso é feio! Só falta o alerta conter os dizeres `"pegadinha do malandro!"` pra completar o insulto :\

A forma mais elegante é simplesmente desabilitar a opção:

```html
<select>
    <option>Muito</option>
    <option>obrigado</option>
    <option>por</option>
    <option>serem</option>
    <option disabled>você não</option>
    <option>os</option>
    <option>melhores</option>
    <option>exemplos</option>
    <option>selecionáveis</option>
</select>
```

Simples, curto e mais fácil de fazer, entender e manter.

Comment: É, acho que no fim vai ser melhor eu mudar a maneira que estou fazendo e desabilitar a opção, é melhor para o usuário! Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

É possível voltar ao valor original usando o [$.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), que guarda uma informação no DOM do próprio elemento. Dessa forma evita-se o uso de variáveis globais ou criação de campos só pra armazenar esse valor. O $.data, ou $(elemento).data, funciona com chave/valor, dessa forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#teste").data('current', $("#teste").val()); // guarda o valor inicial do select com a chave "current"

$("#teste").on("change", function (event){

  var valor = $(this).val();
  if(valor == 4){
    alert('esse valor não pode!');
    $(this).val($.data(this, 'current')); // retorna ao valor inicial/anterior
    return false;
  }
   $(this).data('current', $(this).val()); // atualiza com o novo valor que foi possível selecionar
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="teste">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando Vanilla.

```js
document.getElementById('teste').onclick = function (event){
if(event.target.options) el = event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex]; 
}
document.getElementById('teste').onchange = function (event){
 if(this.value == 4) el.selected = true;
}
```

```html
<select id="teste">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```